# Do you want me as a non-mechanical engineer to ask questions about mechanical drawing symbols?

Tags: discussion, scope

As an electronics hobbyist and student, I often find myself in a situation where I have to interpret mechanical drawings, such as those describing the physical properties of connectors and encapsulations.

Occasionally there are symbols that I do not recognize, and since it is difficult to use Google (*"wavy line in a circle in a box with two numbers on top"*), it would be nice to have a place to ask trivial questions, usually one of these two:

1. What does this symbol mean? How is it significant?
2. I can not find or derive the distance between these two features - why is it not stated?

So, can I ask them here? I would seem like a perfect fit, *except* that it is hard to make such a question interesting or useful for others. "Here's a picture, what does this mean?" is not easy to search for, leading to the questions perhaps being inherently of a low quality.

Comment: An example of a similar question is: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/2764/33  That might help to see an example of a way to ask. (and the kind of information that may be asked for you to provide.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your proposed questions are appropriate to ask on the main site.

Please provide an image of the symbol in question along with some amount of context about what you're working on.

Comment: And if you can *describe the symbol in words* that will help others searching for an answer to discover your question and any associated answers.